# HTTP Error 401 with NLog WebService target with windows auth

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nlog, windows-server-2012

Using NLog webservice target
https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

I am getting a 401 when the target api is using windows auth.

> Error Error when sending to Webservice: ws Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

If I allow anonymous, it all works

Im trying to use impersonation in the call to the logging step.  However, the above exception is generated in the NLog internal log file (i turned that on).

```
 if (user.ImpersonateValidUser())
 {
    try
    {
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        LogEntry l = new LogEntry() 
        { 
            AppName = "MyTestController", 
            LoggedOnDate = DateTime.Now, 
            LogMessage = "this is a test", 
            LogType = 1, 
            ServerName = "dev-test3" 
        };
        logger.Error(l);
    }
}
```

How can I call a webservice target that uses windows auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Webservice target isn't supporting authentication. You could use the [LogReceiverService target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/LogReceiverService-target), see also [How can I enable Security in LogReceiverService (NLog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829519/how-can-i-enable-security-in-logreceiverservice-nlog)